# How to align an image to the left most region of the webpage?

Tags: html, html-parsing

When we include an image in a web page with the following code

```
<html><body>
<img src="http://www.example.com/abc.jpg">
</body></html>
```

The browsers render it so that there is a margin of few pixels to the left and the top. I want the image to stick to the the left and top borders.

Help needed with that.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to inspect the element (works well in chrome), have a look to see what has a margin or padding and override that in CSS. I know by default Chrome applied somethine to the body, can't recall if it is padding or margin though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several options:

1. Use a **[CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)**. Simple example:

   ```
   * { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
   ```
2. Use `position: absolute;` to "forcefully" put the image wherever you want it to be (can be controlled with `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left`.

Answer (score 2):

Those are the body's margins.
I always use this styling in my css file:

`html, body { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: none; }`

or you can write it inline, in your case:

`<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">`

Answer (score 0):

Try  this with CSS

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/abc.jpg" class="left-image">

html, body, img{
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}

img.left-image{
 float:left; /* it may require if you have more elements in same container, not always */
 }
```

or you can always position, example if you want 10px from top and 10px from left

```
img.left-image{
 position:absolute;
 left:10px;
 top:10px;
 }
```

Comment: the float is not required (and you missed the semicolon)